# Embedding Restlets in Mule can't work in Mule 3.1.2

Tags: java, restlet, mule

I configure a flow in mule-config.xml based on the documentation([click here](http://www.mulesoft.org/restlet-transport)). Here is the content in mule-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:tcp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp"
      xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
      xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
      xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
      xmlns:restlet="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/restlet"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.1/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp/3.1/mule-tcp.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.1/mule-vm.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/3.1/mule-cxf.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.1/mule-http.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/restlet http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/restlet/3.1/mule-restlet.xsd">

    <description>
        This configuration uses an HTTP endpoint to receive requests.
    </description>

    <flow name="fuxk">
        <inbound-endpoint   address="http://localhost:9002">
        </inbound-endpoint>
        <restlet:component restlet-ref="helloWorld"/>

    </flow>
    <spring:bean id="helloWorld" class="com.ggd543.mulerestletdemo.HelloWorldApplication"/>

</mule>
```

This configuration uses an HTTP endpoint to receive requests.But when I start up the mule instance , I got the following error:

[image: In valid content was found starting with element 'restlet:component']

It seams that the documentation is based on mule 2.x . How do I change the configuration in mule-config.xml for Mule 3.1.2 ?

Comment: The screenshot seems to indicate you're running Mule 3.1 not 3.2. Is that right? If you run Mule 3.1 you need to use the Restlet module for Mule 3.1 not 3.2.

Comment: Thanks for fixing your question's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace mulesource.org with mulesoft.org in **all** your Restlet namespace definitions.

Comment: I replace mulesource.ogr with mulesoft.org, but the error still exists

Comment: You seem to run Mule standalone: have you installed the Restlet module JARs in Mule (in /usr/lib)?

Comment: Yes, I have put `mule-transport-restlet-1.3.jar` into $MULE_HOME/lib/mule, the dependencies `org.simpleframework-3.1.3.jar` , `org.restlet-1.1.3.jar`, `com.noelios.restlet-1.1.3.jar`,`com.noelios.restlet.ext.simple-1.1.3.jar`,`com.noelios.restlet.ext.httpclient-1.1.3.jar` into $MULE_HOME/lib/usr. But it doesn't work yet

Comment: mule-transport-restlet-1.3.jar is compiled for Mule 3.1.0. But you say you're using Mule 3.2.0...

Comment: It isn't compatible with mule 3.1.2

Comment: If the configuration above is the one you're using, it is logical it still fails. You haven't replaced "mulesource.org" everywhere...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5359/discussion-between--and-david-dossot)